# intuition on annahilator in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

Ive been trying to understand this concept in terms of functionals being hyperplanes.

The annilator of a subspace Y is the set of functionals on X vanishing on Y. If we consider the hyperplanes ( or affine hyperplanes) assosiated with these functionalsis is it true or "right to think" that these hyperplanes all are inside of Y or equivalent,  kind of build up Y in some sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of a functional $x^* \in X^*$ in terms of its kernel, the hyperplane $\ker x^* \subseteq X$, we have that $x^* \in Y^\bot$, that is $x^*$ vanishes on $Y$, iff $Y \subseteq \ker x^*$, that is $Y$ is "inside" these hyperplanes, not vice versa.

To the "make up" point: By the above, we have that 
$$ Y \subseteq \bigcap_{x^* \in Y^\bot} \ker x^* $$
The other inclusion does not hold in general, as the right hand side is always closed being an intersection of closed hyperplanes, but this is the only thing that makes a problem: If $x \in X \setminus \overline Y$, there is - by Hahn-Banach - a functional $x^* \in X^*$ with $x^*|_{\overline Y} = 0$ and $x^*(x) = 1$. Then $x^* \in Y^\bot$ and $x \not \in \ker x^*$. Hence 
$y \not\in \bigcap_{x^*\in Y^\bot} \ker x^*$. Therefore
$$ \overline Y = \bigcap_{x^* \in Y^\bot} \ker x^* $$
In this sense, the hyperplanes "make up" $Y$.